# CS50 filter RGBTRIPLE notation

Tags: c, pointers, cs50

QUESTION UPDATED:

In CS50's  filter.c image is defined as `RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));`

This notation was not covered in the lecture and it's confusing.  I understand that calloc is allocating memory for all the pixels in the image but why the use of the () and why not define it as just `RGBTRIPLE image[height][width];`

Comment: then why not image[][] = calloc... or image =calloc... or can you only allocate memory to pointers?

Comment: is image[] = calloc... valid?  the index management is the same as I can access image[i][[j]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`image[height][width]` is a fixed variable and you cannot allocate memory to it. So you need a pointer, to which you can allocate memory. So that is the "image is a pointer to an array of 'width' RGB triples."

The `calloc` call allocated an array of height of these things, so you can do `image[1]` to get the next row and `image[1][0]` to get the first pix of the second row.

You ask if you could do `image =calloc(..`, with `RGBTRIPLE *image;` and yes, you can do that. But no, you can't do `image[1][0]` because the compiler doesn't know the row size. That is what I mean with that you have to do all the indexing yourself now: `image[1*width + 0]` is the first pix of the 2nd row.

Comment: isn't image[1][0] also the first pix of second row?  so really no extra index management.. ahh, but you're saying you can't do that because the compiler doesn't know the row size.  ahh, now I almost understand

Comment: With the definition of image as `RGBTRIPLE *image;` you can't use `image[1][0]` because the compiler doesn't know the row size, but with the definition `RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width]` the compiler _does_ know the row size. Comprendez vous?

Comment: but wait, why not just define RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]; no need to do calloc at all then

Comment: @DCR, yeah, great, except that you may run out of stack space. Even "probably" for a large image.

Comment: And you can't pass the image than to a calling function.

Comment: so we define 1 pointer (thus the us of ()) with width and then allocate enough memory to hold height*width..  seems a little odd.  Can we do RGBTRIPLE(*image)[height][width] = calloc(...  ??     and if your above reply can't I pass &image?

Comment: I think you can do that. But there is no need for this. The compiler will just ignore the second size. It is absolutely no help.

Comment: "Can I pass `&image`?" With `image[height][width]` it has become a _local_ variable which resides on the stack. You can pass it to another function you call, but you can't return it because it ceases to exist once the function returns.